# Generalized harmonic map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

Let $M, N$ be closed Riemannian manifolds and $c$ be a constant. For a map $f:M\to N$, define the *energy* as

$$E(f) = \frac{1}{2} \int_M\Big( \| df(x)\|^2 - c\| f(x) \|^2 \Big) d\mu(x).$$

When $c=0$, it is called the Dirichlet energy. In this case, there is extensive study on the existence of the minimizer, called a harmonic map.

For general $c\neq 0$, what are the known results on existence of a minimizer? In particular, does a minimizer exist when when $N$ is a unit circle?

I'm hoping to use the energy method to find solutions to the equation $\Delta_M f + cf =0$ on $M$. So if the energy is not well-defined, is there any reference on how to solve the PDE?

Comment: Presumably you have to assume N is embedded in euclidean space

Comment: Yes! I added "Riemannian" manifold in the original post. By Nash's embedding theorem, we can always assume N embeds into some Euclidean space. For the case  of interest that N is a unit circle, it is embedded in R^2.

Comment: When $N$ is the unit circle, then $||f|| = 1$ and you are just changing the energy by a constant factor (the volume of $M$ is fixed). The variational problem is therefore entirely unchanged.

Comment: Also, harmonic maps are generally not the global minimizer. If you want to talk about minimizers you probably want to restrict to particular homotopy classes.

Comment: My point is that the embedding will change the problem. So just saying that $N$ admits an embedding does not make this a well-defined question. You need to assume that $N$ has a FIXED embedding in order to make this a well-defined functional. For that reason, it's less geometric than the harmonic map energy (which only depends on the target metric, even though it's often convenient to embed $N$ in Euclidean space)

Comment: @OtisChodosh It is a good point. I hope to use the energy method to find a solution to this Helmholtz equation $\Delta_M f + c f =0$, which seems defined intrinsically. But as from the post of Willie Wong, it is obvious that even for the case $N= S^1$ with a fixed embedding into Euclidean, the minimizer would still be a harmonic map, not the Helmholtz equation that I was hoping for. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you! That's a good point.

Comment: Note that $\Delta_M f$ is a section of $f^*TM$ while $f$ is a map from $M\to N$. So your equation "$\Delta_M f + cf =0$" doesn't make sense.

Comment: The core problem is that there is no intrinsic definition of $\|f(x)\|$. $f(x)$ is a point in $N$, and, given a point $q \in N$, there is no standard definition of $\|q\|$.

Comment: To play devil's advocate: given any function $s:N\to \mathbb{R}$ you can study the Lagrangian $\int_M \| df\|^2 + s(f) ~\mathrm{dvol}_M$ and look for the critical points. (In fact, you can also generalize by replacing $\|df\|^2$ with other invariants of the pullback metric.) People sometimes study these as they model stationary states of nonlinear elasticity, where $s$ often has thermodynamical interpretations.

Comment: But in this formulation, your ELE looks something like $\Delta_M f + s'(f) = 0$ and then it would not have the type matching problem in @OtisChodosh's comment, since $s'(f)$ has the same geometric type as $\Delta_M f$ (both can be thought of as sections of the pullback of $TN$ to be over $M$ via the map $f$).